# Get location of folder in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have this jsp page where it calls the servlet class.In this servlet class it calls another java class.This java class is then attempting to locate a folder named "profiles".However when I tried running the jsp page on a browser it keeps returning ClassNotFoundException(Is it caused by specifying the wrong directory or missing JAR files?).The question I am asking is:How do I get the correct pathing of that folder?

EDIT:
Here is the code:
In UserClientSearch.jsp:

```
    <form id="form" method="post" action="UserClientServlet">
```

In UserClientServlet.java:

```
    String value = request.getParameter("screenName");
    request.setAttribute("screenName", value);

    UserClientFilterSpam fs = new UserClientFilterSpam();
    ArrayList<String> content= fs.filterSpam(value);
```

In UserClientFilterSpam.java:

```
        try {
        lds.init("profiles");
    } catch (LangDetectException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error encountered: "+ ex);
    }
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet.UserClientServlet] in context with path [/MarcusFYPJ] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.LangDetectException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at servlet.UserClientServlet.doPost(UserClientServlet.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Other than the stacktrace you might want to post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being caused by the fact that `com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.LangDetectException` is missing from the classpath.

You need to make sure that it is included in the deployed web application. If it is a 3<sup>rd</sup> party JAR file it can reside in the web app's `WEB-INF/lib` folder.